# JavaScript destructuring assignment after using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, destructuring

Currently, I am using a regex to reorder a set string of `Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5` to make it read `Under/Over N Giochi Set 1` instead. Currently I use the following to output the data:

```
let marketLabel = 'Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5';
match = regexUnderOver.exec(marketLabel);
browserReturn = match[3] + '/' + match[2] + ' ' + match[4] + ' Giochi Set ' + match[1];
```

However, I would prefer to use destructuring assignment to order the data correctly before assigning it to the `browserReturn` variable. I have tried to follow the conventions on MDN however, it does not make sense to me. I'd be grateful if you could show me using the example I have posted. Full code below:

```
let marketLabel = 'Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5';
const regexUnderOver = /^Set ([0-9.]+) Total Games (Over)\/(Under) ([0-9.]+)$/;
match = regexUnderOver.exec(marketLabel);
browserReturn = match[3] + '/' + match[2] + ' ' + match[4] + ' Giochi Set ' + match[1];
return browserReturn;
```

Comment: Is that `return marketLabel.replace(/^Set ([0-9.]+) Total Games (Over)\/(Under) ([0-9.]+)$/, '$3/$2 $4 Giochi Set $1')` that you are looking for?

Comment: no sorry if it was unclear. It is this which needs destructuring `browserReturn = match[3] + '/' + match[2] + ' ' + match[4] + ' Giochi Set ' + match[1];` particularly the `match` array.

Comment: So, what exactly you want to have in the end? `match` is already an array that contains all the captured texts. You can easily access them via indices.

Comment: i want to destructure them so they are already in order https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want

```js
let marketLabel = 'Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5';
const regexUnderOver = /^Set ([0-9.]+) Total Games (Over)\/(Under) ([0-9.]+)$/;
let [fullmatch, firstNum, over, under, lastNum] = regexUnderOver.exec(marketLabel);
let browserReturn = `${under}/${over} ${lastNum} Giochi Set ${firstNum}`;
console.log(browserReturn);
```

The `[fullmatch, firstNum, over, under, lastNum] = regexUnderOver.exec(marketLabel)` is of interest:

- `fullmatch`  - the whole match
- `firstNum` - Capture group 1 contents
- `over`  - Capture group 2 contents
- `under`  - Capture group 3 contents
- `lastNum`  - Capture group 4 contents